# Convert nested NSArray to array of images for UIScrollview based on selection made

Tags: ios, arrays, uiscrollview, nsarray

I have an array in a plist which holds three arrays of images as follows:

```
<dict>
  <key>ImageArrays</key>
   <array>
      <array>
        <string>Bears.png</string>
        <string>BabyBear.png</string>
        <string>MamaBear.png</string>
      </array>
      <array>
        <string>Birds.png</string>
        <string>BabyBirds.png</string>
        <string>MamaBirds.png</string>
      </array>
      <array>
        <string>Chimps.png</string>
        <string>BabyChimp.png</string>
        <string>MamaChimp.png</string>
      </array>
    </array>
```

Based on a selection made within an iCarousel I want to display one of those arrays in a UIScrollView on another view controller. I'm passing the selection on via the following:

```
[PassInfo myImageArray]
//myImageArray is the array selected.
```

My question is how do I get the pictures from the array selected into another array that feeds the UIScrollview?  I passed the entire array so do I now need to convert the image names to NSStrings and then put in a new array? If so, how?

**EDIT:**
To give more info on what I've done already.

So, I've accessed the outer array from the plist like this:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
  self.stopImageArray = [rootDictionary objectForKey:@"ImageArrays"];
```

Determined the selected array with this:

```
-(void)didSelectItemAtIndex    
    arrayChosen = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[self.stopImageArray objectAtIndex:self.carousel.currentItemIndex]];
    [info setMyImageArray:arrayChosen];
    [allInfo addObject:info];
```

Passed it via a class file with this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *myImageArray;
```

And finally pulled up the selected array on the final view controller with this:

```
chosenArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[PassInfo myImageArray]];
```

So I think I've got the correct NSArray I need, I'm just not sure how to convert that array into an an array filled with the images. Don't I need to create an NSArray with objects or convert the image names to UIImage?

Comment: Don't have an array of images, just an array of image names.  Use [imageNamed](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageNamed:) to load your images into the carousel or whatever.  This will automatically provide caching, so you don't need to worry about "optimizing" the reloading of the image multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First access the internal array of the ImageArrays key. Lets say you have this:

```
NSArray* arrayWithArrays = // Store the first outer <array>
```

Then you can get any of the arrays inside with indexes:

```
NSArray* imageArray1 = arrayWithArrays[0];
NSArray* imageArray2 = arrayWithArrays[1];
NSArray* imageArray3 = arrayWithArrays[2];
```

Just make sure you do not go out of bounds on the `arrayWithArrays`, which you can check by calling the `count` method or just looping through the array like a collection:

```
NSArray* selectedImageArray;

for (NSArray* imageArray in arrayWithArrays)
{
    // Usually should wrap this line with a conditional
    selectedImageArray = imageArray;
}
```

Fill `UIScrollView` with `selectedImageArray` or any of the `imageArrayX` variables. Of course you can store those in a property in your View Controller class.

If you want to store the `UIImage` objects in an array, first you need to loop through imageArray with strings and create the objects. You can accomplish this with the following code:

```
NSMutableArray* images = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSString* imageName in imageArray
{
    [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];
}
```

However I would advise you against storing whole `UIImage` objects in an array. It is better to store the strings, like you do now, but just call the `imageNamed:` method everytime you need to load the image.

Comment: I'm not sure how to convert the NSArray into one that actually has image objects in it. I've edited my question to give more info on what I've done so far and where I'm stuck at.

Comment: I added some more sample code, hopefully it will help you out!

Comment: Gotcha, so the problem is where I'm actually loading the images in.

Answer (score 2):

Just make sure you load the images with: [UIImage imageNamed:yourImage].

Comment: Still can't get it to load. This is the line I'm using, can you spot what I'm doing wrong?                                         UIImageView *newPageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[self.arrayImages objectAtIndex:page]]];

Comment: @Melissa What exactly is "page"? Can you print out `self.arrayImages`?

Comment: Got it!!!! Implementing your code @Legoless and then utilizing imageNamed: (just like you said) did it. I've been working on this for  over a week.....thank you so much!!!!